# Get element number of list while iterating through it

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, purrr

I have a list of the following structure,

`myList <- replicate(5, data.frame(id = 1:10, mean = runif(10)), simplify =F)`

and I want to reduce it with a merge

```
myList %>% reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 'id'))
```

That, however, leads to the following colnames:

```
    id     mean.x    mean.y    mean.x    mean.y       mean
```

While I would like something like

```
 id     mean1    mean2    mean3    mean4       mean5
```

Where the numbers are based on the order of `myList`.

Obviously I could iterate over `1:length(myList)`, but I find this solution unelegant. Other option would be to introduce a check in the reducing function, but that would indue a new linear time search for each element of the list, so I don't believe it to be very efficient.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: What is `a`, what is `reduce`?

Comment: probably `a` is actually `id` ? and `%>% %>%` would be `%>%` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**New answer:**

Using `rbindlist` and `dcast` from the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- rbindlist(myList, idcol = 'df')
dcast(mydata, id ~ paste0('mean',df), value.var = 'mean')
```

Or with the tidyverse packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
myList %>% 
  bind_rows(., .id = 'df') %>% 
  spread(df, mean) %>% 
  rename_at(-1, funs(paste0('mean',.)))
```

which both give (`data.table`-output is shown):

> ```
>     id     mean1       mean2     mean3      mean4      mean5
>  1:  1 0.6937674 0.005642891 0.4155868 0.74184186 0.54513885
>  2:  2 0.3602352 0.569412043 0.8018570 0.29177043 0.34521060
>  3:  3 0.6353133 0.512876032 0.8711914 0.44660086 0.16338451
>  4:  4 0.2106574 0.555638598 0.8240744 0.37495213 0.57443740
>  5:  5 0.9530160 0.059930577 0.0930678 0.39862717 0.91568414
>  6:  6 0.3723244 0.598526326 0.4970844 0.01978011 0.07832631
>  7:  7 0.2923137 0.712971846 0.3805590 0.25676592 0.11682605
>  8:  8 0.6208868 0.426853621 0.5533876 0.64054247 0.78949419
>  9:  9 0.9032609 0.274705843 0.3525957 0.46994429 0.32883110
> 10: 10 0.9707088 0.351394642 0.1089803 0.97969335 0.77791085
> ```

When there are [duplicates in `id`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404066/get-element-number-of-list-while-iterating-through-it/46404283#comment79839589_46404283) in one or more of the dataframes in `myList`, you have to adapt the `dcast`-step to `dcast(mydata, id + rowid(id,df) ~ paste0('mean',df), value.var = 'mean')` to get the correct outcome. Check the following example to see the result:

```
myList <- replicate(5, data.frame(id = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE), mean = runif(10)), simplify = FALSE)
mydata <- rbindlist(myList, idcol = 'df')
dcast(mydata, id + rowid(id,df) ~ paste0('mean',df), value.var = 'mean')
```

This also works when there are no duplicates in `id`.

The `tidyverse`-code has then to be adapted to:

```
myList %>% 
  bind_rows(., .id = 'df') %>% 
  group_by(df, id) %>% 
  mutate(ri = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(df, mean) %>% 
  rename_at(3:7, funs(paste0('mean',.)))
```

---

**Old answer (still valid):**

A possible solution:

```
# option 1
myList <- mapply(function(x,y) {names(x)[2] = paste0('mean',y); x}, myList, 1:length(myList), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 'id'), myList)

# option 2 (quite similar to @zx8754's solution)
mydata <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 'id'), myList)
setNames(mydata, c('id', paste0('mean', seq_along(myList))))
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id     mean1     mean2      mean3      mean4      mean5
> 1   1 0.1119114 0.4193226 0.86619590 0.52543072 0.52879193
> 2   2 0.4630863 0.8786721 0.02012432 0.77274088 0.09227344
> 3   3 0.9832522 0.4687838 0.49074271 0.01611625 0.69919423
> 4   4 0.7017467 0.7845002 0.44692958 0.64485570 0.40808345
> 5   5 0.6204856 0.1687563 0.54407165 0.54236973 0.09947167
> 6   6 0.1480965 0.7654041 0.43591864 0.22468554 0.84557988
> 7   7 0.0179509 0.3610114 0.45420122 0.20612154 0.76899342
> 8   8 0.9862083 0.5579173 0.13540519 0.97311401 0.13947602
> 9   9 0.3140737 0.2213044 0.05187671 0.07870425 0.23880332
> 10 10 0.4515313 0.2367271 0.65728768 0.22149073 0.90578043
> ```

Comment: I don't really want to iterate over 1:length(myList). It is a working solution, but i dont really find it elegant.

Comment: @Joaquin Why don't you find it elegant? Anyway, I've found another solution without using `1:length(myList)`. See the update, HTH

Comment: I dont believe there is anything wrong with your first solution, it was the solution I was using prior to the new one. I was just wondering if there is a way to do it without iterating over indices. It was not really a question about how to get things working, but if there exists a different way to do it.

Comment: @Jaap, dcast answer is ok on sample data but fails on : `myList <- replicate(5, data.frame(id = sample(1:10), mean = 11:20), simplify =F)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper In what way does it fail on your example data? It works perfectly well on my computer ....

Comment: You're right, sorry for wasting your time, I must have done something wrong on my side when I checked (I'll delete both comments soon)

Comment: Actually the problem is for your new solutions if there is some duplicates in `id`, 1st solution is wrong and second crashes, your old solutions work however (this time tested carefully): `myList <- replicate(5, data.frame(id = sample(1:10,10,T), mean = 11:20), simplify =F)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper just use `rowid` in the `dcast` answer: `dcast(mydata, id + rowid(id,df) ~ paste0('mean',df), value.var = 'mean')`

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to modify the `function` in the `Reduce` (or `reduce`) call to make the adding of indices automatic :

```
Reduce(function(x, y){

         # get indices of columns that are not the common one, in x and y
         col_noby_x <- which(colnames(x) != "id")
         col_noby_y <- which(colnames(y) != "id")

         # maximum of indices in x (at the end of the column names)
         ind_x <- max(as.numeric(sub(".+(\\d+)$", "\\1", colnames(x)[col_noby_x]))) 

         # if there is no indice yet, put 1 and 2, else modify names only in y, taking the max value of indices in x plus one.
         if(!is.na(ind_x)) colnames(y)[col_noby_y] <- paste0(colnames(y)[col_noby_y], ind_x +1) else {colnames(x)[col_noby_x] <- paste0(colnames(x)[col_noby_x], 1); colnames(y)[col_noby_y] <- paste0(colnames(y)[col_noby_y], 2)}  

         # finally merge
         merge(x, y, by="id")}, myList)      

#   id      mean1     mean2     mean3     mean4      mean5
#1   1 0.10698388 0.0277198 0.5109345 0.8885772 0.79983437
#2   2 0.29750846 0.7951743 0.9558739 0.9691619 0.31805857
#3   3 0.07115142 0.2401011 0.8106464 0.5101563 0.78697618
#4   4 0.39564336 0.7225532 0.7583893 0.4275574 0.77151883
#5   5 0.55860511 0.4111913 0.8403031 0.4284490 0.51489116
#6   6 0.92191777 0.9142926 0.4708712 0.2451099 0.84142501
#7   7 0.08218166 0.2741819 0.6772842 0.7939364 0.86930336
#8   8 0.35392512 0.2088531 0.0801731 0.2734870 0.62963218
#9   9 0.64068537 0.8427225 0.1904426 0.2389339 0.73145206
#10 10 0.31304719 0.9898133 0.8173664 0.2013031 0.04658273
```

Comment: I know I can do this, and I mention this solution in the question. I dont want to do this due to possible performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

Merge with *Reduce*, then update column names:

```
res <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "id"), myList)
colnames(res)[2:ncol(res)] <- paste0("mean", 1:length(myList))
```

Comment: does reducing and merging warranty that the first column after ID in the end data frame is that of the first element of the list?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `set_names`

```
library(tidyverse)
myList %>%
      reduce(merge, by = 'id') %>% 
      set_names(c("id", paste0("mean", 1:5)))
#   id      mean1       mean2      mean3      mean4     mean5
#1   1 0.07122593 0.480300675 0.34944190 0.48718226 0.9118796
#2   2 0.18375430 0.850652470 0.24780063 0.45148232 0.2587470
#3   3 0.18617054 0.526188340 0.48716956 0.53354343 0.9057241
#4   4 0.87838756 0.811985522 0.49024819 0.10412944 0.7830501
#5   5 0.29287646 0.974811919 0.31413846 0.01508965 0.4587954
#6   6 0.62304018 0.004421152 0.81053625 0.80032467 0.7630185
#7   7 0.78445890 0.006362844 0.73643248 0.15952795 0.4386658
#8   8 0.71568076 0.081139996 0.36933728 0.31771823 0.2794372
#9   9 0.25523328 0.081603285 0.00298272 0.33698950 0.2413859
#10 10 0.86274552 0.432177738 0.26064580 0.75639537 0.3125151
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two one liners

Using `purrr:reduce2` and `dplyr::inner_join` in place of `merge`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
myList %>% reduce2(map(2:length(.),~c("",.x)), inner_join, by = 'id',copy=F)

#    id       mean     mean2     mean3      mean4      mean5
# 1   1 0.44560715 0.4575765 0.6075921 0.06504922 0.90410342
# 2   2 0.60606716 0.5004711 0.7866959 0.89632285 0.09890028
# 3   3 0.59928281 0.4894146 0.4495071 0.66090212 0.56046997
# 4   4 0.55630819 0.4166869 0.1984523 0.08040737 0.18375885
# 5   5 0.97714203 0.1223497 0.7923596 0.53054508 0.93747149
# 6   6 0.07751312 0.6217220 0.3861749 0.30062805 0.03177210
# 7   7 0.22839323 0.3994350 0.6382234 0.98578452 0.27032222
# 8   8 0.73628572 0.8804618 0.8240999 0.44205508 0.73901477
# 9   9 0.81894510 0.2186181 0.9317510 0.60035660 0.65002083
# 10 10 0.26197059 0.5569660 0.9167330 0.58912675 0.81367176
```

Or using `plyr::join_all` and `tibble::repair_names`(same output):

```
myList %>% join_all('id','inner') %>% repair_names
```

Comment: Upon seeing your comment, I tested your answer. It works on the original example as posted by OP, but not on [the case with duplicate `id`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270475/moody-mudskipper) you mentioned under my answer. This might explain the downvote (not mine though).

Comment: @Jaap, I don't see how it doesn't work, I get the same output that I would have with OP's  code `myList %>% reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 'id'))` (apart from the column names). Maybe we understand something differently, I think your solution puts the first instance of mean on the first row (for a given id), and then additional ones on the next rows, filling every missing values with NAs. What I do is successive inner joins, keeping only the common `id` values,

Comment: my second answer uses  `tibble` package for `repair_names`, not `tidyr` as I previously mentionned, now corrected, and cause of downvote possibly identified :).